# Java.lang.NullPointerException at getapplicationContext() while initiating TextView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```java
public final class ConnectAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String>
{
    private MainActivity mActivity = new MainActivity();
    private TextView mTextView;

    // other codes...

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... params)
    {
        // exception throws in this line
        mTextView = new TextView(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

I called `publishProgress(myString + " five");` and want to generate TextView runtime. But `NullPointerException` throws. What's the wrong ??

Could you explain please?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `ConnectAsync ` class constructor to get `MainActivity` context instead of calling `getApplicationContext()` method by creating object of class which is extending Activity

Comment: `new MainActivity()` can't do that. activities are only created by the system, never by the developer

Comment: initiate your textview before you call the Asynctask and then access it within the onProgressUpdate. Also, you cant create activities like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code with **Activity context** instead of **Application Context**:

```java
public final class ConnectAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String>
{
    private Context context;
    // other codes...

    public ConnectAsync(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... params)
    {
        // exception throws in this line
        mTextView = new TextView(context);
    }
}
```

I don't have permission to comment yet.*

Comment: problem solved before you answering, but thanks for attention. :)